# Передача пароля по SSH

Tags: linux, qt, ssh, администрирование

Мне необходимо выполнять команды на удалённом сервере. Для этого вызываю команду:

```
 ssh root@ip 'echo 123'
```

Всё бы ничего, но мне надо передавать одной командой ещё и пароль. Это нужно для того, чтобы использовать эту команду в Qt, потому что из qt я не могу отловить запрос пароля и ввести его.

```
system("ssh root@" TARGET_IP " 'echo 123'");
```

Куда копать?

---

Ключ уже лежит на сервере, но команды в Qt `system("ssh root@" TARGET_IP " 'echo 123'");` выдаёт такие ошибки:

> ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
>   ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
>   ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
>   ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
>   Received disconnect from 192.168.5.161: 2: Too many authentication failures
>   Disconnected from 192.168.5.161

---

На команду `root@ip 'echo 123'` спрашивает пароль всё равно. Ключ лежит в дериктории `/root/.ssh`.

Comment: Вариант авторизации по ключу не подходит?

Comment: Ключ уже лежит на сервере, но команды в Qt system("ssh root@" TARGET_IP " 'echo 123'"); выдаёт такие ошибки: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Received disconnect from 192.168.5.161: 2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 192.168.5.161

Comment: *Ключ уже лежит на сервере* — успешно ли (т.е. без запроса пароля) выполняется команда `ssh root@ip 'echo 123'`, выполненная от того же пользователя, от имени которого вы запускаете свою программу?

Comment: На команду root@ip 'echo 123' спрашивает пароль всё равно. Ключ лежит, в дериктории /root/.ssh

Comment: права на моей стороне на чтение и запить публичного ключа имеются

Comment: для начала: на удалённой машине установите правильные атрибуты на каталог (и содержимое) `/root/.ssh`: `chmod -R go= /root/.ssh`. далее смотрите логи на удалённой машине.

Comment: Я в подобных случаях спользую *псевдотерминал* (на Си [man forkpty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty)) и вручную передаю пароль (и если требуется, "yes" перед ним)

Answer (score 2):

На сервере, (любой редактор) vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
  RSAAuthentication yes
  PasswordAuthentication no /указать NO
   HostKey /root/.ssh/rsa_key.pub  /указать путь к ключу
```